# Modern OpenGL context failure

Tags: c++, opengl

OK, I managed to create an OpenGL context with `wglcreatecontextattribARB` with version 3.2 in my attrib struct (So I have initialized a 3.2 opengl context).

It works, but the strange thing is, when I use glBindBuffer e,g. I still get unreferenced linker error, shouldn't a newer context prevent this?

I'm on windows BTW, Linux doesn't have to deal with older and newer contexts (it directly supports the core of its version).
The code:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    HGLRC tmpRC;
    int iFormat;
    if (!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to create a device context. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = attribs->colorbits;
    pfd.cDepthBits = attribs->depthbits;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    if (!(iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to find a suitable pixel format. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, iFormat, &pfd))
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to initialize the pixel formats. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (!(tmpRC=wglCreateContext(hDC)))
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to create a rendering context. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, tmpRC))
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to activate the rendering context. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    strncpy(vers, (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION), 3);
    vers[3] = '\0';
    if (sscanf(vers, "%i.%i", &glv, &glsubv) != 2)
    {
        CMsgBox("Unable to retrieve the OpenGL version. Program will now close.", "Error");
        return false;
    }
    hRC = NULL;
    if (glv > 2) // Have OpenGL 3.+ support
    {
        if ((wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB")))
        {
            int attribs[] = {WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, glv, WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, glsubv,WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,0};
            hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC, 0, attribs);
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(tmpRC);
            if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
            {
                CMsgBox("Unable to activate the rendering context. Program will now close.", "Error");
                return false;
            }
            moderncontext = true;
        }
    }
    if (hRC == NULL)
    {
        hRC = tmpRC;
        moderncontext = false;
    }
```

Comment: I guess this question belongs to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You will still need to

1. Declare function pointers with the apropriate names and function signatures.
2. Fetch the correct memory locations for those pointers with `wglGetProcAddress`
3. #define the actual OpenGL API names to the corresponding function pointers.

That's right, the OpenGL API functions are actually function pointers.

If you don't have the time and patience to do this, then it is advised to use an OpenGL loader library, like GL3W or GLEW. This'll also save you of the burden of first creating your dummy context and then the "real" context.

Also see the [OpenGL wiki page on loading function pointers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: Then could I ask you, what is the entire USE of creating a newer context then? If need to do the same as with the old context (access new API things with function pointers and declarations like extensions), isn't creating a new context utterly useless?

Comment: @user209347 short answer: no, it isn't useless. Read "Overview" section of [wgl_create_context](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt) for a brief motivation behind it.

Comment: See also wglGetProcAddress

Comment: The functions are not defined inside `opengl32.dll` which hasn't changed on over a decade, but are part of the OpenGL Independent Client Driver (ICD). The `wglGetProcAddress` is just a pass through to the actual implementation within the ICD. The same goes for each and every OpenGL function BTW (except for the fallback 1.1 software rasterizer in opengl32.dll; which you don't want to use).

Comment: @user209347: No, you need to use the new context creation WGL API extensions if you want to do things like use a multisample main framebuffer (you can use FBO-based MSAA without this), create a debug context for use with `GL_ARB_debug_output` or `GL_KHX_DEBUG`, create a core context, etc. You also cannot get WGL pbuffer pixel formats without using the extended WGL API, though if you have PBOs you can ignore this too..

Comment: OK, I see the use. Please correct me: If you don't have modern context, you cant use glbindbuffer e.g. function pointer, instead you have to check for extensions glbindbufferARB and use the function pointer to that extension function. Is this the concrete difference the new context makes for me?

Comment: @user209347: No, that is still wrong :-\ If you have a context whose version is >= 1.4, you know that Buffer Objects are supported (VBOs anyway). The context version dictates that kind of stuff, you still have to check the context version / extension strings before loading the procedure addresses, and you still have to load the procedures manually - better just to use GLEW in the long-run.